# Swagger-ui-express is not rendering the content of API documentation

Tags: documentation, swagger-ui, swagger-ui-express

I'm using [Swagger-ui-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-express) (without JSDOC) in my Express.js app to write documentation for my API. Here's the routing and middleware code (I use `swagger.josn` file instead of writing comments):

```js
const swaggerUI = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerDoc = require('./swagger.json');

app.use('/apidocs', swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(swaggerDoc));
```

When I go to the route specified for reading the documentation, the page is blank and there's nothing rendered:

[image: docs rendering in my browser]

As you can see, the route and the swagger-ui-express middleware are working (there's "Swagger UI" and its icon on the tab's title), but I have no idea why it's not rendering anything.

There's also an error in the browser console:

[image: the error in console]

I'm using [OpenAPI (Swagger) Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=42Crunch.vscode-openapi) VSCode extension to see the preview of documentation and it's rendering OK, which means everything is syntactically correct:

[image: docs rendering with VSCode extension]

I visited this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57368318/14191153), and I checked the response headers. The `Content-Type` is correct and is set to `text/html; charset=utf-8`.

I also sent a request via Postman and I got this:

```html
<!-- HTML for static distribution bundle build -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Swagger UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./swagger-ui.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
    <style>
        html {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

        *,
        *:before,
        *:after {
            box-sizing: inherit;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            background: #fafafa;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0">
        <defs>
            <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="unlocked">
                <path
                    d="M15.8 8H14V5.6C14 2.703 12.665 1 10 1 7.334 1 6 2.703 6 5.6V6h2v-.801C8 3.754 8.797 3 10 3c1.203 0 2 .754 2 2.199V8H4c-.553 0-1 .646-1 1.199V17c0 .549.428 1.139.951 1.307l1.197.387C5.672 18.861 6.55 19 7.1 19h5.8c.549 0 1.428-.139 1.951-.307l1.196-.387c.524-.167.953-.757.953-1.306V9.199C17 8.646 16.352 8 15.8 8z">
                </path>
            </symbol>

            <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="locked">
                <path
                    d="M15.8 8H14V5.6C14 2.703 12.665 1 10 1 7.334 1 6 2.703 6 5.6V8H4c-.553 0-1 .646-1 1.199V17c0 .549.428 1.139.951 1.307l1.197.387C5.672 18.861 6.55 19 7.1 19h5.8c.549 0 1.428-.139 1.951-.307l1.196-.387c.524-.167.953-.757.953-1.306V9.199C17 8.646 16.352 8 15.8 8zM12 8H8V5.199C8 3.754 8.797 3 10 3c1.203 0 2 .754 2 2.199V8z" />
            </symbol>

            <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="close">
                <path
                    d="M14.348 14.849c-.469.469-1.229.469-1.697 0L10 11.819l-2.651 3.029c-.469.469-1.229.469-1.697 0-.469-.469-.469-1.229 0-1.697l2.758-3.15-2.759-3.152c-.469-.469-.469-1.228 0-1.697.469-.469 1.228-.469 1.697 0L10 8.183l2.651-3.031c.469-.469 1.228-.469 1.697 0 .469.469.469 1.229 0 1.697l-2.758 3.152 2.758 3.15c.469.469.469 1.229 0 1.698z" />
            </symbol>

            <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="large-arrow">
                <path
                    d="M13.25 10L6.109 2.58c-.268-.27-.268-.707 0-.979.268-.27.701-.27.969 0l7.83 7.908c.268.271.268.709 0 .979l-7.83 7.908c-.268.271-.701.27-.969 0-.268-.269-.268-.707 0-.979L13.25 10z" />
            </symbol>

            <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="large-arrow-down">
                <path
                    d="M17.418 6.109c.272-.268.709-.268.979 0s.271.701 0 .969l-7.908 7.83c-.27.268-.707.268-.979 0l-7.908-7.83c-.27-.268-.27-.701 0-.969.271-.268.709-.268.979 0L10 13.25l7.418-7.141z" />
            </symbol>


            <symbol viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="jump-to">
                <path d="M19 7v4H5.83l3.58-3.59L8 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41L5.83 13H21V7z" />
            </symbol>

            <symbol viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="expand">
                <path d="M10 18h4v-2h-4v2zM3 6v2h18V6H3zm3 7h12v-2H6v2z" />
            </symbol>

        </defs>
    </svg>

    <div id="swagger-ui"></div>

    <script src="./swagger-ui-bundle.js"> </script>
    <script src="./swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"> </script>
    <script src="./swagger-ui-init.js"> </script>



    <style>
        .swagger-ui .topbar .download-url-wrapper {
            display: none
        }

        undefined
    </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Does anybody know why it's not rendering in the browser?
Is it because of the error shown in the console? If yes, what should I do to get rid of it?
Browser: Brave v1.47.186 (Chromium v109.0.5414.119).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent lots of time on this, and got nothing.

Out of nowhere I just **changed `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`**.

And it's rendered now!

Edit: This problem only happened on Windows 10. On Fedora Linux `localhost` was fine.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the default port

ex:
localhost:3000

to
localhost:8000

works for me